# Add a custom button on navigation bar who open a specific aplication android

Tags: android, addition, edit, navbar

Well i read how change icons colors or add a button on navigation system bar like camera button.

But i want to know if i can add a button that open a especific apliccation like whatsApp or anyone installed like a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

All what you need you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html)

You can open another application from your `onClick` or `onOptionsItemSelected` event.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, in an activity, override onOptionsItemSelected method. Then test the menu item which is clicked and open the application you want to using an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#Build).

```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.MENU_ID:
         Intent i = new Intent();
         i.setFlags(...);
         startActivity(i);
         break;
      }
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
```